# Is the source code available for examples in the "Mathematica Cookbook" by Sal Mangano?

Tags: reference-request

I looked around a bit and didn't seem to find it.  Not as obvious as Wrox books make it, for example.

I came across a pdf of the book online [I paid for the paperback] but pasting the code from the pdf resulted in a bunch of incorrect character substitutions.

Any info on a resource for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visit [the author's page](https://web.archive.org/web/20131225140232/http://mathematicacookbook.com/?page_id=35) (WayBack archive version), where it says this:

[image: sal mangano]

Comment: Ah, yes.  Well, if it was a bear . . . lol Thank you.

Comment: The link is broken 6 years later